# TFS2015: How to set two different build definiton to use the same local repository (git)?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I have two different build definition in TFS2015 as you  can see on the picture Def1 and Def2. They build different solution from the same branch and uses the same VSO build agent (only 1 instance installed on server).
When I queue a build, Def1 build will checkout repository to local in a different folder as Def2. (like : c:\TfsData\Build_work\ee25a947 and
 c:\TfsData\Build_work\faee67a3) but i want to force them to use the same local git repository (because its unnecessary to have two different local repo, they will build different solution with different build steps).
Is there any way to configure it?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Why do you have two solutions in your git repo uf they are built independently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to get the build agent to put both Solutions in the same location. The system assumes, rightly so, that changes may be made to the source as part of the build so it needs to build in isolation.

This is to prevent bleed between the builds.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using your own agents, instead of the cloud agents, then you can do the following:

- Go to your configured work folder
- Go to 'sourceRootMapping\\' folder
- Open the 'SourceFolder.json' and update the directory paths there to the same repository path that you want to use for 'def2' build definition as well.

Below are the values that we had to update:

```
  "build_artifactstagingdirectory": "1\\a",
  "agent_builddirectory": "1",
  "build_sourcesdirectory": "1\\s",
  "common_testresultsdirectory": "1\\TestResults",
```

Once we updated these, then the get sources step between 'def1' and 'def2' build definitions started using the same repository path under "1\"

Make sure that your "SourceRootMappings\Mappings.json" does not have a value of 0 for "lastBuildFolderNumber". If that's the case, and you start using this build agent for a new build definition, it will override your earlier repository.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the process of starting get sources. When you check the build log after build, you'll see:

> Syncing repository: *TeamProjectName* (Git)
>
> Checking out *xxxx* to C:\a\1\s
>
> Checked out branch refs/heads/branch for repository *TeamProjectName*
>   at commit *xxxx*

Actually, the *xxxx* is the latest commit ID in your branch by default, the latest commit will be checked out by default during build. The character/number is the commit ID.